# Invoke SOLR post tool command using Python subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, solr, subprocess

I want to invoke this SOLR post command through Python subprocess:

```
/u01/tony/solr-7.5.0/bin/post -c techproducts /u01/tony/data/bbc/politics/*.txt -params "literal.keywords=politics"
```

I tried firing this using python subprocess module as follows:

```
subprocess.run(["/u01/tony/solr-7.5.0/bin/post -c techproducts /u01/tony/data/bbc/politics/*.txt -params", "literal.keywords=politics"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

But this throws the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/u01/tony/solr-7.5.0/bin/post -c techproducts /u01/tony/data/bbc/politics/*.txt -params': '/u01/tony/solr-7.5.0/bin/post -c techproducts /u01/tony/data/bbc/politics/*.txt -params'
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split all your arguments - the first argument is the command to run.

```
["/u01/tony/solr-7.5.0/bin/post", "-c", "techproducts", "/u01/tony/data/bbc/politics/*.txt", "-params", "literal.keywords=politics"
```

Also, be aware that the `*.txt` expansion is done by your shell, so if the command is not invoked in a shell context (.. which it isn't here), it won't be expanded. However, since the `bin/post` tool accepts a directory as a direct parameter and has a `-filetypes` parameter, you can use

```
"-filetypes txt", "/u01/tony/data/bbc/politics/"
```

.. instead.

The `bin/post` tool is also a shell script, so if it doesn't allow direct invocation (I'm not sure how this is resolved), you might have to prepend the invocation array with

```
"/usr/bin/env", "bash"
```

as well.